Determine reading on gauge that doesn't have enough tick marks
Is there a way to determine what the reading is on this voltage gauge using graphics and math? For example, in a computer program, could I draw a circle and then plot evenly-spaced tick marks (between 14v and 19v) along the circle to see where the dial indicator lies?

Practically speaking, I could guess that the reading is something like 14.5 volts. But it just annoys me that I have to guess.
2010 Silverado 1500; Gas

Yes, but why? As long as it is just above 14 no worries. Analogue gauges are faster to "read" than digital, because eyes register a position change easier...

@SolarMike The LED work lights I installed are making a high-pitched ringing noise. The light manufacturer suggested I check to see if the voltage is too high. He said normal vehicle voltage is around the 13v to 13.5v range. So I'm just curious what voltage my truck is producing and if it's high enough to be causing the problem. https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/96995/48765

The lack of gradation on the gauge may suggest it's not terribly precise - the design is clearly not intended for the user to be reading off tenths of a volt. You could get a protractor and make a million tick marks, but that wouldn't mean you could use the gauge to measure values to the millionth of a volt.

@User1974 the "normal" vehicle voltage with newer battery technology can go up to 15.3V and I know because it is in the workshop manual AND I have measured it with a decent quality (Fluke) meter... That light manufacturer is out of date, barely good enough for dynamos.

A gage with markings every 4 volts is probably not accurate to a decimal point.

Calibrate and find out.

You will have to use a digital or analogue multimeter to measure the voltage input to the gage so that you can get an accurate assessment of the gage reading.  Then you can vary the voltage input to the gage, repeat the multimeter readings, and determine the value shown by the revised gage reading. This is usually the case when trying to assess or calibrate readings on indicator gages such as the one you have shown. A means of independent measure is necessary to calibrate the gage.

the gauge may not be a voltmeter at all ... it may be a servo that is controlled by something else

Estimating at a voltage with uncertainties in the $\pm$ 0.5 V range is about the best you can expect by eye. To do better, photograph (image) the gauge straight on (perpendicular to the plane of the gauge) and print out the image at a reasonable size. Find the center of the horizontal 9 <-> 19 and vertical 14 perpendicular lines. Use this cross point as the radial center of the gauge. Measure the angle $\theta$ from the 9 horizontal dash to the gauge reading in radians. Your gauge reading $V$ will be
$$ V = (10/\pi)\ \theta + 9 $$
By example, $\theta = 90^o = (\pi/2)$ translates to $V = (10/2) + 9 = 14$ V, whereas $\theta = 135^o = (3/4)\pi$ translates to $V = (3/4)(10) + 9 = 16.5$ V.
To first order, the uncertainty on the reading done this way will be a linear propagation of the uncertainty on angle $\delta \theta$ (in radians) from your angle gauge and the angular uncertainty (in radians) on finding the positions of the markings for 9, 14, 19, and the gauge itself $\delta s$. A rough relative uncertainty equation would be
$$\left(\frac{\Delta V}{V}\right)^2 = \left(\frac{\delta \theta}{\theta}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\delta s}{2\pi}\right)^2 $$
You could also invest in a precise, linearly-scaled gauge with more tick marks.

Yike! I needed my coffee. I've posted a solution to make up for my mistake.
